# TSQL XML - Filter Nodes LIKE 'x' on Cross Apply

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, nodes

With the following XML:

```
<Path>
    <To>
        <Value>
            <Array>
                <NumberDecimal>10.0</NumberDecimal>
                <TextEnglish>Ten</TextEnglish>
                <NumberRomanNumeral>X</NumberRomanNumeral>
            </Array>
        </Value>
    </To>
</Path>
```

How would I filter the following cross apply to all/only `Number***` xml nodes?

```sql
SELECT child.value('concat(local-name(.),": ",.)', 'varchar(max)') AS [value]
FROM imports i
CROSS APPLY i.import_data.nodes('/Path/To/Value/Array/*[local-name(.) = ''NumberDecimal'']') AS nodes(child)
```

returns:

> NumberDecimal: 10

Needs to be this:

```sql
SELECT child.value('concat(local-name(.),": ",.)', 'varchar(max)') AS [value]
FROM imports i
CROSS APPLY i.import_data.nodes('/Path/To/Value/Array/*[local-name(.) = ''Number/*'']') AS nodes(child)
```

Need to return:

> NumberDecimal: 10
>
> NumberRomanNumeral: X

But it returns nothing....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `[contains(local-name(.),'Number')]'` [demo](http://rextester.com/VKOJQ17284)  to find elements whose name *contains* the string `Number`

```
Declare @x xml = '<Path>
    <To>
        <Value>
            <Array>
                <NumberDecimal>10.0</NumberDecimal>
                <TextEnglish>Ten</TextEnglish>
                <NumberRomanNumeral>X</NumberRomanNumeral>
            </Array>
        </Value>
    </To>
</Path>'


SELECT child.value('concat(local-name(.),": ",.)', 'varchar(max)') AS [value]
FROM (SELECT @x as import_data)  i
CROSS APPLY i.import_data.nodes('/Path/To/Value/Array/*[contains(local-name(.),''Number'')]') AS nodes(child)
```

or `[substring(local-name(.),1,6) eq "Number"]` to find elements where the string is in a certain place (in this case the start)

For anything more exotic you are probably best off doing it in TSQL

```
WHERE child.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname')  LIKE '[SomeExpression]'
```

Comment: `Your XML in the question is not valid as the closing tags don't match the opening ones.` - Fixed. Sorry for the poorly written example.

Comment: +1 for 'contains' but I do want control of where the wildcards are (`%` in TSQL), I found an article that says I can use a function called `matches` but that doesn't exist for me.

Comment: @TaterJuice - yep SQL Server only implements a few XQuery functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-functions-against-the-xml-data-type

Comment: but substring is one of those so if your aim is to search an exactly specified offset in the string then that is do-able.